# Managing only a subdomain in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

My website's domains are currently managed by a domain provider called [mijndomein.nl](https://www.mijndomein.nl/). The aws hosted services are connected simply by subdomains using elastic-IPs. Because of some infrastructural changes, I'd like to start using Route53 for certain subdomains. As there are several other things managed by the domain provider and changing the whole infrastructure all at once seems dangerous, I'd like to manage only *some* subdomains in Route53.

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHuQExY360I) video, which shows how to manage the whole site in Route53 by adding the Route53 name servers for the custom domain provider.

My first question is if it's possible to keep the already existing subdomains at my domain provider and manage only specific subdomains in Route53? If I add the aws nameservers will my domain provider continue to route to elastic-IPs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes

2) Yes, but be careful here: you don't want to change name server for your (root) domain name like they did at 2:58 of that video. Instead you have to go to DNS service provider's console (DNS service provider may or may not be the same place where you registered your domain - from mijndomein.nl web site it looks like they only offer domain regitration but I may be wrong) - that is the same console where you point your usual hostnames (www.example.com for example) to IP addresses, but instead of `A` record you will create a `NS` record(s) that will delegate your newsubdomain's name resolution to appropriate AWS name servers.

```
newsubdomain.example.com    NS    ns-xxx.awsdns-yy.com
newsubdomain.example.com    NS    ns-aaa.awsdns-zz.org
newsubdomain.example.com    NS    ns-bbb.awsdns-qq.net
newsubdomain.example.com    NS    ns-ccc.awsdns-pp.co.uk
```

([example](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/view-tutorials/create-delegate-subdomain-managed-dns-domain/))